# Align Input Elements

Tags: html, css

**I have some input fields as shown in the image below.**

[image]

**and I want it such that the inputs are aligned as shown in the next image.**

[image]

**the problem arises when I introduce the helper text. To solve this I tried to absolute position the helper text but this causes it to overflow into next element.**

So I wanted some help in achieving the desired outcome.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-size: larger;
}
.layout {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
}
.layout-item {

    border: 1px dotted red;
    word-wrap: break-word;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    position: relative;
}

.helper-text {
    color: cadetblue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum earum sed magnam adipisci cum? Repellendus iusto quo aut tempore perferendis.</div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.    </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper textasdsaddasdsadasd</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.    </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper textasdsaddasdsadasd</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum earum sed magnam adipisci cum? Repellendus iusto quo aut tempore perferendis.</div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where should the "helper text" be in relation to the other content within each of these `layout-item` items?

Comment: The helper text should be below the input element only.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a flex class to the containing element, the `.input-wrapper` elements, you can then assign an `order` to the individual items within to control where they appear within the flexbox. The following will place the `"helper text"` above the input element but if it is required that the `"helper text"` appear below the input simply change the `order` numbers around or assign a higher number to the `.helper-text` class

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-size: larger;
}
.layout {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}
.layout-item {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}
.helper-text {
    color: cadetblue;
}



.input-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:1rem 0 0 0;
}
.input-wrapper > input{
  order:1;
  max-width:50%;
  min-width:150px;
}
.input-wrapper > .helper-text{
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum earum sed magnam adipisci cum? Repellendus iusto quo aut tempore perferendis.</div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.    </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper textasdsaddasdsadasd</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.    </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper textasdsaddasdsadasd</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="layout-item">
            <div class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum earum sed magnam adipisci cum? Repellendus iusto quo aut tempore perferendis.</div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="helper-text">This is my helper text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Helper text should be below the input field only. Changing the order to position the helper text below the input field will result in the same situation as earlier. But still thanks for responding.

Comment: I edited the `order` having read your comment regarding position and disagree that it results in the same behaviour that you illustrated in the above image. Run the snippet - it is below the input and wholly within the parent container - if that is not the expected result please try to be clearer in the desired output